# Releasing memory space allocated by new using free()

Tags: c++, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

As I understand, `delete[]` is used to release the memory space allocated by `new`. `free()` can also be used to release that memory space. So which type of problems will I have to face when releasing memory using `free()` in place of `delete[]`?

Comment: free() is used for memory allocated by malloc() et al.

Comment: A `delete` call calls an object's destructor, where the object is instantiated with `new`. A `delete[]` call runs destructors on an array of objects instantiated with `new[]`. Running `free()` does not call the destructor. This is only relevant for C++, not for C.

Comment: They come in pairs: `new` and `delete` are `C++`, `malloc` and `free` are `C` but can also be used in `C++`. Please don't mix the pairs.

Comment: Your pairing is wrong: new/delete, new[]/delete[] and malloc(other mallloc)/free - never break that (in addition the placement new/delete)

Answer (score 5):

> *"`free()` can also be used to release that memory space."*

No, `free()` cannot be used to release memory allocated with `new()` or `new[]`.

> *"So which type of problems will I have to face when releasing memory using `free()` in place of `delete[]`?"*

Using `free()` instead of `delete[]` for memory allocated with `new[]` is *undefined behavior* (besides destructor functions of complex objects won't be called), and such may likely end up with a runtime exception.

From the [POSIX compliant reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/free.html) (emphasis mine):

> *The `free()` function shall cause the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated; that is, made available for further allocation. If ptr is a null pointer, no action shall occur. Otherwise, if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by the [`calloc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/calloc.html), [`malloc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html), [`posix_memalign()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/posix_memalign.html), [`realloc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/realloc.html), or [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html) function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free() or [`realloc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/realloc.html), **the behavior is undefined**.*
>
> *Any use of a pointer that refers to freed space results in undefined behavior.*

Well, some implementations of `new[]` or `new()` might rely on that `malloc()` function family, others may not. So you can't certainly tell that allocated memory pointer can be safely used with free (even if you don't care about the destructor function call issue).

---

**Conclusion:**

Usage of `delete[]` is only well defined to operate on memory that was allocated using `new[]`, `delete` corresponds to results of `new`.

As well usage of `free()` is only well defined in conjunction for memory that was allocated using the `malloc()` function family.

---

<sub>As far concerning the [c](/questions/tagged/c) tag applied to your (original) question, since c doesn't support `delete` or `new` asking this for the c language is pretty useless.</sub>